# Writing a reference-type function to be used as L-value to process its R-value

Tags: c++, function, lvalue

I noticed that sample code for reference-type functions on the web and in books all have only a return line (like the following which is from MSDN)

```
class Point
{
public:
  unsigned& x();
private:
  unsigned obj_x;
};

unsigned& Point :: x()
{
  return obj_x;
}

int main()
{
  Point ThePoint;
  ThePoint.x() = 7;
}
```

I think if I include more lines (artithmetic expressions, control structures, etc) in a reference-type function, they will only change its behavior when it's used as a normal  (R-value) function. But how could I write a function that, when used as an L-value, will do some arithmetic on its R-value (here the number 7) or checks it against some conditions, before putting it into the return variable (here `obj_x`)?

Comment: What you want to achieve seems very cryptic and counter-intuitive in my opinion. Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @JBL I want to know if `ThePoint.x()` has to accept the r-value (7) the way it is or is it possible to do some processing on it. Is there such a feature in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean is **very** conterintuitive. But this can not be achived that way.

What you want is ordinary done with the help of proxy objects, like it is done in `std::vector<bool>` specialization. When you using it like `v[i] = true;`, `v[i]` returns proxy object, that have overloaded assignment operator, which rises `ith`  bit in internal bit-string.

Example:

```
struct A
{
   struct proxy
   {
      proxy(int * x)
         : x_(x)
      {       
      }

      proxy & operator = (int v)
      {
         *x_ = v + 2;
         return *this;
      }

      operator int() const
      {
         return *x_;
      }
    private:
      int * x_;
   };

   proxy x_add_2()
   {
      return proxy(&x_);
   }

   int x() const
   {
      return x_;
   }
private:
   int x_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   A a;
   a.x_add_2() = 2;
   std::cout << a.x() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```